# RestTemplate.getForObject()

Tags: java, spring

Does anyone know how the RestTemplate.getForObject() maps to on object without specifying the properties. When I use this,

```
public Data GetDataFromService()
    {
        RestTemplate rest=new RestTemplate();
        rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        Data dt=rest.getForObject(url, Data.class);
        return dt;
    }
```

everything except the userid property is populated from the json the is provided.

```
package com.ameren.models;


public class Data {
    private String userId;
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    public Data(String UserID,String ID, String Title, String Body)
    {
        this.userId=UserID;
        this.id=ID;
        this.title=Title;
        this.body=Body;
    }
    public Data()
    {

    }
    public void setID(String ID)
    {
        this.id=ID;
    }
    public void setUserID(String UserID)
    {
        this.userId=UserID;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title)
    {
        this.title=Title;
    }
    public void setBody(String Body)
    {
        this.body=Body;
    }
    public String getUserID()
    {
        if(userId==null)
            return "No UserID";
        else
            return this.userId;
    }
    public String getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return this.title;
    }
    public String getBody()
    {
        return this.body;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your settter method should be called `setUserId` in order to correspond with the name of your property. That may to be the problem.

Comment: I did that too and it still did not work... How does spring know how to map? There is no code to do the map the object. However spring is doing it. What I don't understand is how its missing this one property.

Comment: Can you update the question with a JSON snippet?

Comment: Jackson does the job, not RestTemplate. @EdwinDalorzo is right: are you sure you tried with "setUserId" and not "setUserID"? Case matters. (By the way, in Java, vars get a lower case first letter ;) )